# Coalesced global memory writes using hash

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpgpu

My question concerns the coalesced global writes to a dynamically changing set of elements of an array in CUDA. Consider the following kernel:

```
__global__ void
kernel (int n, int *odata, int *idata, int *hash)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n)
    odata[hash[i]] = idata[i];
}
```

Here the first `n` elements of the array `hash` contain the indices of `odata` to be updated from the first `n` elements of `idata`. Obviously this leads to a terrible, terrible lack of coalescence. In the case of my code, the hash at one kernel invocation is completely unrelated to the hash at another (and other kernels update the data in other ways), so simply reordering the data to optimize this particular kenrel isn't an option.

Is there some feature in CUDA which would allow me to improve the performance of this situation? I hear a lot of talk about texture memory, but I've not been able to translate what I've read into a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texturing is a read-only mechanism, so it cannot directly improve the performance of scattered writes to GMEM.  If you were "hashing" like this instead:

```
odata[i] = idata[hash[i]];
```

(perhaps your algorithm can be transformed?)

Then there might be some benefit to considering a [Texture mechanism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-texture).  (Your example appears to be 1D in nature).

You might also make sure that your shared memory/L1 split is optimized towards cache.  This won't help much with scattered writes though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I have various places in my code where I encounter exactly the situation you describe (scattered reads from global memory). These reads are truly random (and typically sparse) in the array. A texture mechanism is worth looking into in this case?

Comment: Texturing may help in that case.  Texturing still depends on data locality and re-use in order to provide any benefit.  If the net effect of your scattered reads is that you are only reading each location once, then texturing won't help.  But if you are potentially reading some locations more than once (perhaps from multiple threads) then texturing may give some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you limit the range of hash outcome? For example, you may know that first 1K iterations of threads would access in the range of 0 to 8K of `odata` only.

If so, you can use shared memory. You may allocate block of shared memory and do fast scatter write on shared memory temporarily. Then write back the shared memory block to global memory in coalesced transactions.