# Un-coalesced global memory access caused by indirect access in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

My CUDA programm is suffering from un-coalesced global memory access. Although the idx-th thread only deal with the [idx]-th cell in an array, there are many indirect memory accesses as shown below.

```
int idx=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;

.... = FF[m_front[m_fside[idx]]];
```

For m_fisde[idx], we have coalesced accesses, but what we actually need is FF[m_front[m_fside[idx]]]. There is a two-level indirect access.

I tried to find some patterns of the data in m_front or m_fsied in order to make this to be a direct sequential access, but found out that they are almost 'random'.

Is there a possible way to tackle this?

Comment: This is effectively the same problem as sparse matrix addressing, and there has been rather a lot of work done on understanding how to improve that. You might get some ideas from looking at the literature on sparse matrix operations on GPUS.

Comment: If there is any locality in the accesses, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938333/coalesced-global-memory-writes-using-hash/12938726#12938726) may be of interest.

Comment: @RobertCrovella... The **Texture Mechanism** link provided in the above linked answer, is expired. Can you please update the link?

Comment: @sgar91 The link is fixed now.

Comment: @thierry Please, see my revised and improved answer.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Texture is of course a good solution. But, my data is large and arrays are many. I am afraid that if I utilize texture memory I will have many texture memory replacement operations which may bring new overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Accelerating global memory random access: Invalidating the L1 cache line**

Fermi and Kepler architectures support two types of loads from global memory. **Full caching** is the 
default mode, it attempts to hit in L1, then L2, then GMEM and the load granularity is 128-byte line. **L2-only** attempts to hit in L2, then GMEM and the load granularity is 32-bytes. For certain random access patterns, memory efficiency can be increased by invalidating L1 and exploiting the lower granularity of L2. This can be done by compiling with `–Xptxas –dlcm=cg` option to `nvcc`.

**General guidelines for accelerating global memory access: disabling ECC support**

Fermi and Kepler GPUs support Error Correcting Code (ECC), and ECC is enabled by default. ECC reduces peak memory bandwidth and is requested to enhance data integrity in applications like medical imaging and large-scale cluster computing. If not needed, it can 
be disabled for improved performance using the nvidia-smi utility on Linux (see the [link](http://johanneshabich.blogspot.it/2011/04/nvidia-cuda-disableenable-ecc.html)), or via Control Panel on Microsoft Windows systems. Note that toggling ECC on or off requires a reboot to take effect.

**General guidelines for accelerating global memory access on Kepler: using read-only data cache**

Kepler features a 48KB cache for data that is known to be read‐only for
the duration of the function. Use of the read‐only path is beneficial because it offloads  the Shared/L1 cache path and it supports
full speed unaligned memory access. Use of the read‐only path can be managed automatically by the compiler (use the `const __restrict` keyword) or explicitly (use the `__ldg()` intrinsic) by the
programmer.

Comment: Thanks very much. Invalidating the L1 Cache line make sense for me. I will try this to see whether the mem efficiency can be increased. And, read-only data cache in Kepler is also a good advice. I am not quite familiar with new characteristic of Kepler. Let my try. However, I do need ECC support.